# Port VB6 MDIForm application to VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

I have looked here for solutions, but they seem to be different than the situation I am encountering.
I have a MDIMain.frm, I have its "IsMdiContainer = True". I have another form in which I set objForm1.MdiParent = MDIMain, I show the objForm1.Show and the MDIMain. But the only thing that comes up is the MDIMain, which is completely empty.

The MDIMain is supposed to be completely empty, the design was to swap any of 4 'child' forms on to it.
I ran the VB6 to VB.Net conversion tool from VS.2005 to 'port' the project from one language to the other. Of course there were tons of issues, but I have the program running and the initial parts of the code seem to be ok. It is just this MDI parent/child issue I see right now.  The program does not initially open the main MDI form but some other forms and then the main MDI form with the correct child connected.

I found a very simple MDI parent/child example https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-visual-basic/0596000936/ch04s04.html and could get that to work.

In the New() of the 'Child' form this code is from the converter:

```
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
    'This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    'This form is an MDI child.
    'This code simulates the VB6 
    ' functionality of automatically
    ' loading and showing an MDI
    ' child's parent.
    Me.MDIParent = UniProg.MDIMain
    UniProg.MDIMain.Show
    Form_Initialize_renamed()
End Sub
```

Which kind of looks OK, setting the child' parent to the MDI Form of the project. Then it shows the MDI form. Not seen here, but the MDIMain.Load is being called as a side effect of a

`Col_Plus_Calib.Add(MDIMain.UC_Status)`

call. This is what I see from the Call stack, after placing a break-point in the MDIMain_Load routine. Then the MDIMain_Load routine I hard coded

```
    frmPlus.MdiParent = Me
    frmPlus.Show()
```

To show the child form.

One of the suggestions commented about the order of these operations so maybe that is the issue. but I'm fuzzy on those details. So maybe the objects are not created in the correct order or created at all?

Comment: Without more code, it would be difficult to help you narrow down the problem.  In any case, there is quite a bit new to .NET these days.  I don't know what your application does, but you might find it easier to essentially rewrite it than to try to automatically convert it and clean up the resulting issues.

Comment: Have you checked in `Project-> Properties->Application` what is the starting Form of your app? You should also post the code where you *show the objForm1.Show and the MDIMain* (I hope not in that order :)

Comment: Don't put the answer into the question.  Post the answer instead.